# Where do I find an authoritative reference material containing \string and others?

Tags: documentation

The best documentation on \string that I found was https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Plain_TeX#Special_control_sequence_name

I searched the following materials, but they didn't explain \string.

- http://tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html
- http://ctan.org/
- https://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/doc.html
- http://texdoc.org/
- http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/usrguide.pdf

I think I also experienced a similar lack of documentation on a few other commands. Where can I find a comprehensive reference material online?

Comment: Knuth, Computers & Typesetting.

Comment: `texdoc texbytopic` or http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf

Comment: texbytopic and texbook are both decent materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find quite detailed information about TeX primitives in V. Eijkhout’s “TeX by Topic”, which is [free for download on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic).

The particular primitive you are mentioning, that is, `\string`, is quite easy to describe: it will expand to a printable representation of the next token (which will be consumed in the process). The result will be a string of characters of category code 12 (but spaces will be of category code 10); if the next token is a control sequence, the string will represent its name, preceded by the character corresponding to the current value of `\escapechar`, but there will be no character if the parameter’s value is not in the range 0–255 (`0x000000`–`0x10FFFF` for XeTeX or LuaTeX).

For instance,

```
\string\x
```

will produce `\x` (two character tokens with category code 12) if `\escapechar` has the default value of 92 (the ASCII code for the backslash). No interpretation is done to the token following `\string` and only one token is in its scope.

With e-TeX engines (like `pdftex`), you can use `\detokenize` for stringifying more tokens at once.